# Not able to access redis port inside a docker container, bind 0.0.0.0

Tags: docker, redis

I have installed Redis on an Ubuntu 18 server and it is bind to 0.0.0.0.

Inside that host I have installed Docker as well. If I'll try to connect to the port from the host itself it will work (curl hostIP:6379)

The problem appears when I'm creating a docker service and exec to that container. If I'll try to curl from there I'm receiving: `curl: (1) Received HTTP/0.9 when not allowed`

The think is that on the same server I have installed RabbitMQ, Elasticsearch and curl on those ports it is working (inside docker container as well), only Redis has that issue.

Any idea?

Thanks,

LE: I founded the issue, is this image: `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/runtime:3.1.1-alpine3.10`

but still ... why it is not working inside it?
I'm also asking as I think there is an environment where it is working inside it, and an environment where it is not

Comment: Try changing the `protected-mode yes` to `protected-mode no`

Comment: Did that but still not working

Comment: `curl` only makes HTTP request; Redis isn't an HTTP service (nor is RabbitMQ, but its management interface is).

Comment: Of course, the idea is that I can't reach the port :-) ... so ... there is another idea ... and still I can't figure it out